# Vuejs - parent array changes but child does not see that prop change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-class-components, vue-property-decorator

I have this in a parent:

```html
{{ fencing }}
<FencingTable
   v-if="fencing.length > 0"
   :fencing="fencing"
   :facility="facility"
/>
```

```js
get fencing() {
   return this.$store.state.fencing;
}
```

I have this in the child:

```html
<template>
   <div>
   {{fencing}}
...
```

```js
export default class FencingTable extends Vue {
   apiLocation = Vue.prototype.$apiLocation;
   @Prop() fencing: Fencing[] | null = null;
   @Prop() facility: Facility | null = null;
      ...
}
```

When I update my store and add the first item to the array, I see the parent render the item but the child shows an empty array. If i reload the page everything works and subsequent adds to the array show up everywhere correctly.

How do I make my child properly update when the first item is added to the array?

Comment: make get fencing a `computed property` instead of a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `vue-property-decorator` [guide](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator#each-props-default-value-need-to-be-defined-as-same-as-the-example-code-shown-in-above):

> It's not supported to define each default property like @Prop() prop = 'default value'

In other words, don't specify a default value that way using `=` but like:

```js
@Prop({ default: null }) fencing: Fencing[] | null;
@Prop({ default: null }) facility: Facility | null;
```